# How can I pass commands to the elevated application in a batch file?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I was wondering if anyone can help me. I'm currently working on a game engine project which involves its own c++ compiler. For this I'm "borrowing" the visual studio 2013 c++ compiler. everything works fine. The problem I am having is a cant figure out how I would pass commands to the elevated program in a batch file.

Let me Explain, right now I am using a program which calls the `"vcvarsall.bat"` file and passes in `"x86"` as a parameter. This is great for manual entry as it then allows me to input the commands to compile files. E.G `"cl /EHsc <cpp files>"`

As of now, when I add commands after I call `"vcvarsall.bat"`, they just give me a command reference error saying the command is not recognized.

What I want to achieve is being able to call one bat file which executes and compiles all of my code for me. instead of having to manually type in the commands every time. This way the entire process is easier for the user.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That .bat file sets up the compiler/linker environment.  You can look at that file and see where it launches the cmd.exe window and modify it so it executes a command of your choosing.  Check this link for example: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html.

Answer (score 0):

> when I add commands after I call "vcvarsall.bat"

Maybe it has been too long since I last did a batch file .. hope the following gets you started:

I think any .bat file will accept parameters, and internally, the .bat writer (i.e. you) uses special identifiers. Often they are named something like %1 and %2, etc.  (some scripting languages use $1, and probably a few other approaches)

Without consuming these parameters in your .bat file, the command line interpreter tries to use the parameter as another command (so you get 'command not recognized')

Search all .bat files on your system for %1 (or $1 or whatever) ... maybe you'll find enough hints.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, the way I solved the problem was by finding the last batch file which was called and making the end of the file call another batch file in the main compile directory, this means I can programatically generate this batch file making it incredibly easy to generate custom compilations. thank you all,

Alister